# Makefile does not see my implicit rule

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I am trying to make worlds simplest (relatively generic) `Makefile`. I can use to drive a small series of tests to learn C. For some reason, `Makefile` refuses to understand my implicit rule to make object files form `c: %.o: %.c`, I get `no rule to make target %.o` needed by `test1.exe`. Below is my `Makefile` in entirety:

```
INC     = sglib
CC      = gcc
LD      = gcc
LDFLAGS =
# On MS-Windows, say "make os=win" to set proper extensions
os  = 
SO  = 
EXE =  

ifeq ($(os), win)
SO  = dll
EXE = .exe
# -fPIC is a no-op on Windows, but causes a compiler warning
CFLAGS  = -std=gnu99 -ggdb3 -Wall
else
SO  = so
CFLAGS  = -std=gnu99 -ggdb3 -Wall -fPIC
endif


all: test1$(EXE)

test1$(EXE): %.o
    $(LD) $< -o $@

lib-test.$(SO): %.o
    $(LD) -shared $(LDFLAGS) -o $@ $<

%.o: %.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -I$(INC) -c $< -o $@

check:
    echo Nothing yet!

.PHONY: all clean 

clean:
    rm -f *.o *.$(SO) test1$(EXE)
```

I am using [msys](http://www.mingw.org/wiki/MSYS) on windows 20 with `gnu make 4.2.1` and `gcc 6.2.0`. I am puzzled what is wrong there. it is probably something simple but I seem to be blind at the moment.

Comment: `%.o: %.c` tells Make that it can compile `anything.c` to get `anything.o`. However, `test1$(EXE): %.o` tells Make that it can link `%.o` (which is gotten by compiling `%.c` using that rule) to get `test1$(EXE)`. Do you have a file called `%.c`?

Comment: Whauh! To be honest I don't understand what you guys are doing here. 


"Please use the edit link on your question to add additional information. The Post Answer button should be used only for complete answers to the question. - From Review – Morten Jensen 6 hours ago"


I didn't want to add additional information, I wanted to thank those that answered my post and confirm they were helpful and pointed me to correct place.  And now I am even banned from posting anwers :-).


I am quite confused, but anyway, thanks for the help, enjoy yourself and have a good life everybody.

Comment: @user1648090 The way you thank those that answered is by upvoting their answers and/or accepting the most helpful. See [what to do when someone answers](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers). Also, please take a look at the [tour].

Comment: @user1648090 The reason your answers were downvoted are because they're not good answers. People are allowed to answer their own questions, but the answers are held to the same standard as if you weren't the same person who asked the question.

Comment: Rolled back. You must not change the question once you got answers (this does not disallow adding relevant information), as that leaves them without context. If you don't want to play by the rules, maybe you should not join a community.

Answer (score 3):

This:

```
test1$(EXE): %.o
```

defines a rule which states that the prerequisite of the target `test1` is the file `%.o`. Not some wildcarded list of object files. *Specifically* the file named `%.o`. You have no other rule in your makefile to create that file, and it doesn't currently exist, hence the error that you get.

`%` only acts as a placeholder in [Pattern Rules](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Pattern-Intro) (and similar functions like `patsubst`), which are rules where `%` appears in the *target*. So your:

```
%.o : %.cpp
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -I$(INC) -c $< -o $@
```

is a pattern rule, because of the `%` in `%.o`. This does not create a rule building the target `%.o`, but rather any file with suffix `.o`. This would apply when trying to build target `foo.o` - we'd create an implicit rule with preqrequiste `foo.cpp`, with the stem `%` matching `foo`.

What you *actually* want is to wildcard your object files. There's a function for that:

```
test1$(EXE) : $(wildcard *.o)
```

But this doesn't actually work either. When you try to build the first time, there aren't any object files that exist yet. Clearly. So `$(wildcard *.o)` would return an empty string, and you end up with nonsense. So you can't wildcard them. You need to explicitly provide that string:

```
test1$(EXE) : $(object_files)
    $(LD) $< -o $@
```

Now we just need to come up with that list:

```
source_files := $(wildcard *.c)
object_files := $(source_files:.c=.o)
```

Now if you have source files like `foo.c`, `bar.c`, and  `baz.c`, the `$(wildcard)` function will find them and set `source_files` to `foo.c bar.c baz.c`. The substitution on the next line will set `object_files` to `foo.o bar.o baz.o`. So we end up with `test` depending on those three object files, and you already have a pattern rule to build those object files.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be thinking that in rules like this:

```
 test1$(EXE): %.o
```

the % sign is a wildcard character which cause filename expansion - it isn't. If you want to create a list of .o files, you should use the built-in `wildcard` function.

I have a couple of blog articles on generic makefiles starting at https://latedev.wordpress.com/2014/11/08/generic-makefiles-with-gcc-and-gnu-make/ which may (or may not) be useful.